# Set focus to kendo ui textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I can't seem to find any good answers on the internet. Standard way for input by using jQuery focus isn't working.

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.VisibleName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.VisibleName)
    </div>
```

This is part of a form in kendo UI grids pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Normal javascript works for me

```
@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(x => x.VisibleName))
```

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var field = $("#VisibleName");

        $("#test").click(function () {
            field.focus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delay the focus for a moment:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#inputName").focus();
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out. hope this will help you..

```
$("input[name='VisibleName']").focus();
```